# Python Math Regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing, math, language-design

I am creating a programming language in Python and one main component that I'm missing for the basic language is the ability to parse mathematical equations.  I have the function to parse the math but I need to be able to check if the input is a math equation.  I'm looking for a regex to match something like 3*x^(4*y)+1-(7*y*z/x).

Comment: Although a regular expression may *check* such input, I'm skeptic how much you can rely on it to *validate* the equation.

Comment: No, a regular expression can't even *check* if it is syntactically correct.

Comment: @aioobe: Just because Python’s patterns aren’t up to the task doesn’t mean nobody’s is. [Many are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes/4843579#4843579). You know this. Please stop parroting.

Comment: Right... I'm commenting on this from the perspective of "pure" regular expressions, i.e., those that check for containment in a regular language. I agree, some engines have extensions which makes them as powerful as any CFG parser.

Answer (score 10):

You can't do what you want with regular expressions, it isn't a regular language. Python has extensions that you could abuse to do what you want but it would be un-maintainable and would not gain you anything over using a parser.

What you want is a Parser, a great easy to use library for Python is called [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Here is a related [answer with a pyparsing example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string/2371789#2371789).

Comment: pyparsing is absolutely the right tool for the job here. Parsing simple irregular grammars is precisely the task that pyparsing excels at.

Answer (score 2):

> ***I'm looking for a regex to match something like `3*x^(4*y)+1-(7*y*z/x)`.***

You can't have a regular expression that matches strings such as "3*x^(4*y)...". The languages of well-balanced parenthesis is simply **not [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)**.

(Actually, when talking about Python specific regular expressions, the above is a lie. Still though, I would claim that regular expressions would be the wrong tool for this task.)

> ***I have the function to parse the math...***

If you have a parser, I suggest you simply attempt to parse it, and say `true` if it succeeds, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: ʀᴇɢᴜʟᴀʀ sᴍᴇɢᴍᴜʟᴀʀ. So use a better pattern matching library then.  Hint: Python can match `(.*)\1` too, and that isn’t regular either. .

Comment: Hm.. right. Still though, I don't believe regular expressions is the right tool for this... do you?

Comment: Updated answer anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an actual expression parser.  Here is a question about expression parsing in Python:

[Math Expression Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545403/math-expression-evaluation)

And here is the link from the best answer:

http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm

Comment: *I have the function to parse the math* -- Seems like he already has a parser...

Comment: I'm not sure.  What parser function is there that can parse the expression but doesn't tell you whether it succeeded or not?  I'm not sure what he actually has.

Comment: I think he means that he has a function that can evaluate a parsed expression.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing math text, [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) is often used. If you get your input in this syntax, then you can use a RPN python function to read it.

For a RPN parser in python, either [this](http://calcrpnpy.sourceforge.net/) or [this](http://criptonita.com/~nacho/blog/2011/02/23/reverse-polish-notation-evaluation-in-python/) looks promising.

If your are writing your own programming language, you can simply force the user to use this notation, and check if it is not in RPN :)

Comment: I enjoy RPN myself, but his example clearly shows he wants infix.  His example: 3*x^(4*y)+1-(7*y*z/x)

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you intended me to take this comment.

Comment: Twas a joke: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjQtzV9IZ0Q

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can use a recursive function that recognizes letters and numbers and then when parsing expressions, say for example "x+y", it checks whether "x" and "y" are valid math.  So whenever you are validating an expression, if it is a letter or a number it is valid or if it is an operator with valid stuff on either side.