# Pattern Matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, math

I'm working on java program that can compute the differentiation of any given mathematical expression. 
When User types the expression say `Sin(Cos(x^2))` I need to check whether it is mathematically valid or not.
Of course we can do it by manual code writing but that would be tedious work.
Can I do it using **regex** package of java??

How??

thanx..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, regexes aren't sufficient... (in fact, this can be mathematically proved).

To parse mathematical expressions, you can either write your own parser (which isn't actually that hard) or use an existing one, such as [Jep](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/).

Here are some previous SO questions on parsing mathematical expressions:

[Best algorithm for evaluating a mathematical expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572796/best-algorithm-for-evaluating-a-mathematical-expression)

[Reading and running a mathematical expression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400050/reading-and-running-a-mathematical-expression-in-python)

[Evaluating mathematical expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151127/evaluating-mathematical-expressions)

Answer (score 6):

[JEval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/) is a decent alternative, seeing as JEP is now under a commercial license.

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to accept *any* mathematical expression  then regex will not work for you.

you will need to use a parser to check your expression and decide if its valid or not base on a specified mathematical grammar.

have a lot at [antlr](http://www.antlr.org)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to code it yourself then you can use [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) which is widely used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is the [JScience](http://jscience.org/) library. The abstract class [Function](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/function/Function.html) includes a `differentiate()` method, which is implemented for discrete, polynomial, and rational functions.

Answer (score 0):

Computer algebra systems (like for example Mathematica) use rule notations like the following for differentiation:

```
  D[Cos[x_],y_]:=(-1)*Sin[x]*D[x,y]
  D[Sin[x_],y_]:=Cos[x]*D[x,y]
```

these transformation rules are also sometimes called "pattern-matching rules", but they have nothing to do with regex pattern-matching for strings.
See [Introduction to Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html) for more information.

I know these open source Java projects, which contain a similar pattern-matching rule engine:

- [Symja/Matheclipse](http://bitbucket.org/axelclk/symja_android_library/wiki/Home) (my own project)
- [MathPiper](http://code.google.com/p/mathpiper/) (a Java fork of the [Yacas](http://yacas.sourceforge.net/) project)
- [omath.org](http://code.google.com/p/omath/) (SVN at omath.org site seems to work?)